# How to limit touch events to a specific region or UIView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

How do I limit touches to a specific region or `UIView`?

In other words, I have a `UIButton` on the view but it seems to be disabled by the touches.

I should also write that the touches do what I want, but, like I said, I lost control of the `UIButton`s.

```
@Implementation
...


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    ...
}


- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    ...
}


- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    ...  
}
```

---

I solved my problem...

(My error) I made a smaller UIView with the UIButtons positioned outside of it.  The subview was attached to that UIView.  (I could see the buttons, but I couldn't even press them)

Solutions(2 of them worked):

- addSubview of UIButtons to self.view
- or...   enlarge the smaller UIView to 340 x 480.

Comment: Could you provide more details? How you handle touches, what's your view hierarchy?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your view (where you defined `touchesBegan` et al.) does not forward the touches to the next responder in the responder chain (among which there are your buttons), you could try to call [super] in all of those methods, i.e.:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    ...
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

and the same for the other methods. See also the discussion [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan%3awithEvent%3a).